# Phonegap - Android Build Error

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

Here's what I did.

In the command line:

```
$ phonegap -v
5.3.6

$ phonegap create myfirstproject
Creating a new cordova project.
Downloading hello-world-template libarary for www...
Download Complete

$ cd myfirstproject

$ phonegap remote login
[phonegap] Phonegap/Build Login
[phonegap] Sign up at build.app.com
 [warning] Github accounts are unsupported
  [prompt] enter username: myusername
  [prompt] enter password: **********
[phonegap] logged in as myusername

$ phonegap remote run android
[phonegap] compressing the app
[phonegap] uploading the app
[phonegap] building the app
   [error] error occured while building the android app
```

Then I go to https://build.phonegap.com and login. I go to my apps, and click the "android" and redirects me to my project builds. I click the "Log" button and I got this:

```
-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 43 source files to /project/bin/classes
    [javac] /project/src/org/apache/cordova/filetransfer/FileTransfer.java:692: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         if (!isLocalTransfer && !Config.isUrlWhiteListed(source)) {
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method isUrlWhiteListed(String)
    [javac]   location: class Config
    [javac] /project/src/org/apache/cordova/inappbrowser/InAppBrowser.java:122: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                                 || Config.isUrlWhiteListed(url)) {
    [javac]                                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method isUrlWhiteListed(String)
    [javac]   location: class Config
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 2 errors

BUILD FAILED
/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:716: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:730: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 6 seconds

/project/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/project/build.xml
```

Anyone knows about this error? How can we solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just found the answer!

The reason why I got those errors because the phonegap/cordova move their plugins source to **NPM**.

Here's what I did to solve the problem.

I update all the "**plugin name and its source**" in the **config.xml**, so like:

from this:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
```

to this:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" />
```

Now, I successfully build the app. =)

**Reference**:

- http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap-5-2-0-is-now-available-on-build
- http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html

Comment: you also want to add versioning to your workflow. This FAQ will explain why: [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) Read **6. Not setting the "phonegap version" for your compiler**